# How can I override a property defined in build.gradle?

Tags: gradle

How can I set a property in the build.gradle file and allow each developer to override it locally? I tried:

gradle.properties:

```
MY_NAME = "Jonathon"
MY_COLOR = "blue"
```

build.gradle:

```
ext.MY_NAME = "John Doe"
task showit <<{
  println "MY_NAME[" + MY_NAME + "]";
  println "MY_COLOR[" + MY_COLOR + "]";
}
```

`gradle showit` gives:

```
:showit
MY_NAME[John Doe]
MY_COLOR["blue"]
```

I thought that a property defined in a gradle.properties file at the project root would override a property with the same name defined in build.gradle, but this does not appear to be the case. It only fills in for a missing property.

Comment: Hi Rachel. I couldn't see where it answered my question. The example you gave shows a local variable, but I couldn't override it outside of the build script. The Ant task link was for replacing values in a file. If I'm missing something and you can show how I can override a build.gradle property from the gradle.properties file, I'd be glad to accept it.

Comment: oh ok i thought you got it to work. Never mind :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check whether the project has a property, and if not, set it to the default value:

```
ext {
    if (!project.hasProperty('MY_NAME')) {
        MY_NAME = 'John Doe'
    }
}
```

See: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sub:checking_for_project_properties

If you need to do this for multiple properties, you can define a function:

```
def setPropertyDefaultValueIfNotCustomized(propertyName, defaultValue) {
    if (!project.hasProperty(propertyName)) {
        ext[propertyName] = defaultValue
    }
}

ext {
    setPropertyDefaultValueIfNotCustomized('MY_NAME', 'John Doe')
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Johan, that does what I need. BTW, the ext {} around the function calls isn't required.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to [Johan Stuyts' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33414019/606662), but as a one-liner:

```
ext.MY_NAME = project.properties['MY_NAME'] ?: 'John Doe'
```

Running `gradle -PMY_NAME="Jeff F." showit` gives `MY_NAME[Jeff F.]`.

Running `gradle showit` gives `MY_NAME[John Doe]`.

Answer (score 1):

i think you can define a local variable and then override it like this

```
  def dest = "name"

  task copy(type: Copy) {
     from "source"
     into name
  }
```

see [this](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/writing_build_scripts.html) doc

Comment: other wise if you're using apache you should be able to fire off an ant "replace" task that does what you want: 

see http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replace.html

Comment: Thanks,Rachel. I tried overriding the 'dest' variable with a value defined in the gradle.properties file, but it still used the value defined in the build script.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this myself. My use case is that I fork project repos and my coworkers don't. I needed to set the repository remote for [axion-release](https://axion-release-plugin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/repository/) to `upstream` instead of `origin`.

I didn't want to have to pass args (or create aliases/shell functions) so I ended up creating a `gradle.properties` in my `GRADLE_USER_HOME` (`~/.gradle`) and adding a property (name doesn't matter) for this there as well as in the project's `gradle.properties`. In `gradle.build` I always use that property [since it always exists](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html).

#### Example

`~/.gradle/gradle.properties`

```
scmVersionRepositoryRemote=upstream
```

---

`[project-root]/gradle.properties`

```
scmVersionRepositoryRemote=origin
```

---

`[project-root]/build.gradle`

```
scmVersion {
  repository {
    remote = scmVersionRepositoryRemote
  }
}
```