# Override gradle project.ext params from command line

Tags: gradle, groovy

I have a gradle build, where I use properties from another gradle file:

*build.gradle*

```
apply from: "props.gradle"
```

The *props.gradle* is just a set of properties in a file with groovy syntax:

```
ext {
    jdbcJarFile = "/jdbc/lib/ojdbc6.jar"
    system_oracle_driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
    system_db_admin_user = "system"
}
```

Later in the build I can access this properties like this:

```
project.property("jdbcJarFile")
```

What I need is a way to override any of the property defined in `props.gradle` from command line.

E.g.

```
gradle build -PjdbcJarFile=new/path
```

But when I try this, I still get value declared in the `props.gradle`.

I need to be able to override every property, and I have dozens of them in that file. Checking manually for every property is not an option here.

How can I solve this?

Gradle version is 2.12.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think you have to change your `props.gradle` to check for the property, and set `ext.jdbcJarFile` if it isn't set on the command line, ie:

```
if(!hasProperty('jdbcJarFile')) {
    ext.jdbcJarFile = "/jdbc/lib/ojdbc6.jar"
}

ext {
    system_oracle_driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
    system_db_admin_user = "system"
}
```

---

To set this up in a cleaner way for when you have loads of properties, change `props.gradle` from:

```
ext {
    jdbcJarFile = "/jdbc/lib/ojdbc6.jar"
    system_oracle_driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
    system_db_admin_user = "system"
}
```

To something like:

```
def defaultProperty(String name, defaultValue) {
    if(!hasProperty(name)) {
        ext."$name" = defaultValue
    }
}

defaultProperty 'jdbcJarFile', '/jdbc/lib/ojdbc6.jar'
defaultProperty 'system_oracle_driver', 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver'
defaultProperty 'system_db_admin_user', 'system'
```

Comment: But I need to be able to override every property, and I have dozens of them in that file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388458/how-can-i-override-a-property-defined-in-build-gradle

Comment: You will need to rewrite your `props.gradle` script to use a function as shown in that link above